# How to prepopulate projection result with existing left model in linq left join query

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following code (simplified) using linq to sql with left outer join:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        IList<Payment> paymentsList = new List<Payment>() { 
                new Payment() { ID = 1, Amount = 4 } ,
                new Payment() { ID = 2, Amount = -11 } ,
                new Payment() { ID = 3, Amount = 11 }
            };

        IList<Allocation> allocationList = new List<Allocation>() { 
                new Allocation(){ OriginalID = 1, ReversalID=2},
                new Allocation(){ OriginalID = 2, ReversalID=3}             
            };

        var summaryPayments = from s in paymentsList 
                            join alloc in allocationList on s.ID equals alloc.OriginalID into allocOrg
                            from po in allocOrg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join allocRev in allocationList on s.ID equals allocRev.ReversalID into allocRevs
                            from pr in allocRevs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new Payment{Amount=s.Amount, ReversalId = (pr != null ? pr.ReversalID : 0)};

        foreach (var obj in summaryPayments)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", obj.Amount,obj.ReversalId);
        }

    }

}

public class Payment{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
    public int? ReversalId { get; set; }    
}

public class Allocation{
    public int OriginalID {get;set;}
    public int ReversalID { get; set; } 
}
```

I works but I wonder if it's possible to prepopulate projection result model with properties from existing model without manually initializing all of them and just populate properties from 'right' sets, for ex. for the above case I would like to be able to write something like:

```
var summaryPayments = from s in paymentsList 
                            join alloc in allocationList on s.ID equals alloc.OriginalID into allocOrg
                            from po in allocOrg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join allocRev in allocationList on s.ID equals allocRev.ReversalID into allocRevs
                            from pr in allocRevs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select () {var model = s; model.ReversalId = (pr != null ? pr.ReversalID : 0);return model;};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
            var summaryPayments = (from s in paymentsList
                               join alloc in allocationList on s.ID equals alloc.OriginalID into allocOrg
                               from po in allocOrg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               join allocRev in allocationList on s.ID equals allocRev.ReversalID into allocRevs
                               from pr in allocRevs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new { s, pr }).Select(x => { x.s.ReversalId = (x.pr != null ? x.pr.ReversalID : 0); return x.s; });
```